# Youtube data apis 3.0: how to get channel video urls using video.list api?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using youtube data apis 3.0. I want to get the NDTV channel videos to publish in our site.
I can get the list of videos description and some other basic info, but I want information like file details, ratings, liveStreamingDetails, player, processingDetails, recordingDetails, statistics, status, suggestions, topicDetails etc...

can any one please help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to grab the last 50 (maximum allowed) videos of a user with Youtube with Api 3.0

//search channels of user

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername={USERNAME}&key={KEY}
```

//search playlist items of upload channel

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId={PLAYLIST}&key={KEY}
```

//search videos of the playlist items of the upload channel

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id,snippet,contentDetails,status&id=BBfPP0rTjxo,o04cSB5afGc&maxResults=50&key={KEY}
```